# jQuery Draggable in Overflow Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small HTML page, where you can drag list items out of a div container, which has a lot of content, so it is set to `overflow:scroll` (for making it scrollable).

As described in the documentation, I should set the list items to `scroll: false` if I drag it out of a scrollable container. Only with the `helper: clone` is it possible to drag the list items out of the container. But that is not what I want here. `appendTo: body` seems only to work with `helper:clone` (see here: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo), which I cannot use because of visual feedback (`li` items disappear in list if added to 'breakfast').

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('ul li').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  zIndex: '10000',
  appendTo: 'body',
  scroll: false,
  start: function(event,ui) {},
  stop: function (event,ui) {}
});
```

And it can be tested on http://jsbin.com/dinaqabipi/4/. (code: http://jsbin.com/dinaqabipi/4/edit?html,output).

How to make the li containers visible when dragging it out of the overflow container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by inline-style position: relative. You should set the position of the dragging list item to absolute and when not dragging to static.
Try this:

```
#right ul > li {
  position: static !important;
}

#right ul > li.ui-draggable-dragging {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: I also found another solution out, which uses `helper: clone` and toggles the visibilty of the dragged item. see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13165826/734432